# Proof by induction for all natural numbers for successor function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

The two rules to be used to prove $6^3=216$ are : $a^0=1$ and $a^{S(b)}$.

I am having trouble proving the successor function rule although I know that it is equivalent to $(a^n) \times a$.

Sorry for the poor formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use rules that I have used to define the exponentiation operation $x^y$, to prove that $3^3 = 27$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3152528/how-can-i-use-rules-that-i-have-used-to-define-the-exponentiation-operation-xy)

Comment: $a^{S(n)}$ must be **defined** as $(a^n) \times a$.